# Update MySQL table with Java 

Tags: java, mysql, html, jsp

I am trying to update the prices of the cars but I am only able to update one of the items in the database. I think my logic is wrong.

Can someone suggest to me how to solve it.

MySQL Table:

```
 +-----------+-----------+
 | car       | price     |
 +-----------+-----------+
 | Bmw       |    434312 |
 | Audi      |    222121 |
 | Mercedes  |     33333 |
 +-----------+-----------+
```

HTML Code:

```
                       <td><input TYPE="text" NAME="Bmw"></td>

                       <td><input TYPE="text" NAME="Audi"></td>

                       <td><input TYPE="text" NAME="Mercedes"></td>
```

Java Code:

```
  String Bmw=(String)session.getAttribute("Bmw");
    session.setAttribute("Bmw",Bmw);
    Bmw=request.getParameter("Bmw");

 String Audi=(String)session.getAttribute("Audi");
    session.setAttribute("Audi",Audi);
    Audi=request.getParameter("Audi");

 String Mercedes=(String)session.getAttribute("Mercedes");
    session.setAttribute("Mercedes",Mercedes);
    Mercedes=request.getParameter("Mercedes");




 try {
    Connection conn = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn =       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
    Statement st = null;
    session.setAttribute("st",st);
    st = conn.createStatement();
    String sqlqueryCommand = "select * from item";
    ResultSet results = st.executeQuery(sqlqueryCommand);


    while(results.next()) {
            if(request.getParameter("Bmw")!=null &&    results.getString("car").equals("Bmw")) {
                    st.executeUpdate("update item set price='"+Bmw+"' where   car='"+results.getString("car")+"'");
                    conn.commit();
            }
            if(request.getParameter("Audi")!=null && results.getString("car").equals("Audi")) {
                    st.executeUpdate("update item set price='"+Audi+"' where car='"+results.getString("car")+"'");
                    conn.commit();
            }
            if(request.getParameter("Mercedes")!=null && results.getString("car").equals("Mercedes")) {
             st.executeUpdate("update item set price='"+Mercedes+"' where car='"+results.getString("car")+"'");
             conn.commit();
             }  
    }
    conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype of the columns in the database?

Comment: try changing the commit to one line before the close, or debug by printing the results and request values; btw which one is working?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Do you have any error messages? And beside some offtopic: maybe you want to use some prepared statements instead of a string concatenation.

Comment: the datatype for price is int(11) and for car text

Comment: i am trying to change the prices. the only one that i can change the price is for "Mercedes"

Comment: ok, try this, remove or comment the mercedes lines, check if one of the others are now working. if so, try changing the commit to before conn.close()

Comment: I'm not sure if calling update inside a select command is correct, I mean maybe the result is being overriden.. in which case you would have to store the updates in strings and execute them after the results loop

Comment: i removed the the Mercedes lines and now only audi updates

Comment: What's the error showed?

Answer (score 1):

What do you need the select for? You know the results of that one in advance.

This part:

> String Bmw=(String)session.getAttribute("Bmw");
>   session.setAttribute("Bmw",Bmw);

does not make too much sense. Maybe you did not want to retrieve the value from the session but from the request?

Beware of sql-injections. Use prepared statements and parameter placeholders instead.

Here is a proposal on how you can do things a little shorter and safer. It is from memory on how jdbc works, untestet.

```
String[] types = new String[]{"Bmw", "Audi", "Mercedes"};
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("update item set price=:price where car=:car");
for(String type : types)
{
  String parameterValue = request.getParameter(type);
  if (type != null)
  {
    statement.setObject("price", parameterValue);
    statement.setObject("car", type);
    statement.executeUpdate();
  }
}
statement.close();
```

Additionally in your catch block you might want to use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e);`, which will be way more helpful when debugging.

P.S.: Are you sure that your car column items do not contain any whitespace? Print your `results.getString("car")` on any loop.

Answer (score 1):

Beware when you are traversing your results. You're a updating the table while reading it.

You don't need the Select query since you already have the database metadata.

```
results.getString("car").equals("Bmw")
```

rendering this line useless

```
where   car='"+results.getString("car")+"'"
```

both statement should be replaced by a simple Where statement:

```
where car='Bmw'
```

if you have hardcoded the car type once and shoud use this all along. This allows you to perform updates only. In doubt watch the state of your resultset after `con.commit()`